# Convert the number of bits to the 32-bits integer

Tags: rust, type-conversion, bit

I need to convert the number of bits, which goes from CIDR notation to actually subnetwork mask. For example `192.168.0.1/30`. Here is `30` - the number of bits that are set in the network mask (in this example - `255.255.255.252`). I make it by converting the number of bits to actually string and then use a `u32::from_str_radix` method to get the actual number (which I can use for `Ipv4Addr` struct since it has `From<u32>` trait implemented). Here is the code:

```rust
let bit_length = 30
let bits = format!("{:0<32}", "1".repeat(bit_length as usize));
net_mask = IpAddr::V4(u32::from_str_radix(bits.as_str().into(), 2)?.into());
```

I'm wondering is there another way, maybe more elegant, to convert the number of bits to integer when we know the size of the target number (32-bit in this example)? Maybe some bit's magic I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the first 30 bits to be 1, that means the last 2 bits should be 0. So, we can get a number where every bit is 1 by taking the bitwise not of 0, then shifting it left two bits to make the two 0s.

```rust
let bit_length = 30;
let bits: u32 = (!0) << (32 - bit_length);
let net_mask = IpAddr::V4(bits.into());
println!("{:?}", net_mask);
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5d8dea99d51e4439a91c1155c5e66053)

Comment: That's exactly what I need, thank you very much @Aplet123!